# AND Gmail's To and From fields

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'd like to create a Gmail filter that combines the To and From fields with an AND. The default behavior seems to combine these fields with an OR.

For example, the below filter will return results of emails either from dude@email.com OR to guy@email.com.

[image]

Unfortunately this is not what I want. I would like to filter emails only from dude@email.com AND to guy@email.com. The filtered emails can't just reference one of them - it has to be both.

So far I've tried writing it out in a search like this:
`from:dude@email.com AND to:guy@email.com`

But that just yields a filter like this:
[image]

All that did was put 'AND' in the "Has the words" field.

How can I specify a filter so that both conditions are satisfied (and not just one of them).

Comment: What are the results you get? Which emails are not included? What are the ones you find have in common?

Comment: Some emails are from dude@email.com. Some emails are to guy@email.com. Some are from dude@gmail.com and to guy@email.com. I only want the latter

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following filter in the `Includes the words` field, leaving everything else blank.

The results will be ALL and ONLY the emails `from:dude@email.com AND to:guy@email.com`

```
{(from:dude@email.com) AND (to:guy@email.com)}
```

[image]

Comment: I will try to let you know if this works after getting some emails. Thank you 

Comment: I thought you already had some. :) So we were looking for non-existing emails? Then how did you get the results [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/148171/and-gmails-to-and-from-fields/148174?noredirect=1#comment134761_148171) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148171/117311)? Anyway... 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Sorry - I do have existing emails. I was in a rush with my previous comment and misspoke. The problem is that your filter isn't behaving as expected. I'm trying to figure out if I specified the problem incorrectly or if your solution doesn't work. When I'm done with that I'll let you know

Comment: Hope you get it right.